# Please explain how this function .reduce works

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
function countInArray(array, value) {
  return array.reduce((n, x) => n + (x === value), 0);
}
console.log(countInArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3], 4)); // 3
```

I was watching for explanation in manuals, but it seems to me very complex to understand.

So I get that 0 is the starting total, and that x===1 should be equal to 1 or 0 depending on the truth.

I'm mainly confused with n because I read that n is the return value of the previous function, but there's no previous function in the beginning.

Comment: That's why you provide the starting value, zero, *because* there's no previous function.

Comment: Call it "accumulator" rather than "return value of the previous function" (since - as you note - it doesn't have to be the return value of anything). You explicitly set the initial value of the accumulator to `0`. Thereafter, accumulator is the result of the function. If you don't set the initial accumulator value, then accumulator is set to the first value, and the function is not invoked for it (i.e. `reduce` does one iteration less).

Answer (score 4):

> but there's no previous function in the beginning.

Exactly - The "previous function" doesn't exist at the start - so `n` starts off as `0`, the second argument you passed to `reduce`. The [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) give you the argument list:

```
arr.reduce(callback(accumulator, currentValue[, index[, array]])[, initialValue])
```

The last argument there is `initialValue`, which is exactly what it sounds like - it is the *inital value of `accumulator`*.

Answer (score 0):

```
function countInArray(array, value) {
  return array.reduce((n, x) => n + (x === value), 0);
}
console.log(countInArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3], 4)); // 3
```

the above `countInArray` function look up the no of instances of given value in given array.
in JS `true` is equal to `1` therfore `0 + 1` is `2` and so on.

`countInArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3], 4)` here you are trying to count the no of inctance of `4` the answer is 3.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function countInArray(array, value) {
  return array.reduce((n, x) => n + (x === value), 0);
}
console.log(countInArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3], 4)); // 3
```

Lets break it into parts:

1. The function countInArray intends to count occurrences of the value (not necessarily a number) in a given array. Therefore accepts an array and a value.

   2. The reduce function works on the given array. it gets 2 params: a function and a initialization value for the accumulator.
      the function also get 2 params: an accumulator (n in this case) and a current value (x in this case). They are both accessible in every iteration, but the accumulator's keeps its value between iterations while the current value varies at each itaration (possess a new array value).
   3. In every iteration we ask if the current array value equals the value we entered in step 1, if so, we increase by 1 the accumulator (which was initialized to 0 ).

*. The line `n + (x === value)` can be a little confusing. notice that in javascript 1 + true equals 2 and 1 + false stays 1.